# Unordered list won't show bullet within WordPress custom theme post

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

I have an unordered list within a WordPress blog post that will not show the bullets. I've tried multiple things to get it to show, but it will not.

Here's the link (text above the desktop image):
http://www.sherigarvin.com/work-project-3/

Here's what I've tried:

- Removed the ul/ol rule in the css reset
- Added specific ul rule with list-style:disc; & list-style-type:disc; Added list-style:disc; to css reset
- Added general rule to style.css with list-style:disc; & list-style-type:disc;
- Inline style of list-style-type:disc;

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding a `margin-left` to the `li` elements, or, possibly, declaring: `list-style-position: inside;` (which will place the `disc` inside of the width of the `li` element, to demonstrate whether the rule's applying or not).

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 1.5em; /* which should give space for the disc to show */
    list-style-position: inside; /* will put the disc inside of the li
                                    element, for debugging purposes */
}
```

References:

- [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type).
- [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-position).

Comment: That was it, thanks for saving my forehead from anymore bruises!

Comment: I added list-style: disc inside none; on a general ul rule.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to look at is to see if you had `display:block` on the css element somewhere. By removing `display:block` it will make the list style appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inline style that I used on UL that seemed to work better:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;
margin-left: 2.5em; 
list-style-position: outside;">
```